# how to remove [ and ] from string in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I'm trying to remove [ and ] characters from a string in R, I have tried the following code:

```
gsub("[]", "", p1)
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Try this: `gsub("[\\]\\[]", "", p1)`.   The first argument of `gsub()` is a  regular expression and the left and right brackets are special characters that denote a class of characters, and `"[]"`,matches nothing.  I updated the regex string accoring to @BondedDust's comment

Comment: Read up on character classes in ?regex where this is specifically addressed: `gsub("[][]", "", "yy][]oo]")
[1] "yyoo"`. I'm not getting success with Jthorpe's solution but am with this pattern: `"\\]|\\["`

Comment: My original regex sting (`'}{

Comment: My original regex string (`"]["`) matched a `]` followed by a '[', which obviously wasn't correct...this pattern `"[][]]"` is an expression class with two members ( `[` and `]`) and '\\\[|\\\]' matches `[` or `]`.   Note the double escape characters -- one to escape the \ in the R string, the other to escape the `[` in the regular expression.

Comment: As per BondedDust's comment above, his first example is only briefly mentioned in the `?regex` documentation, but in using character classes it works because in order to include a `]` in a character class it must appear first in the list.  `gsub("[][]", "", p1)` is the solution I prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `[]` indicates an invalid character class in which it should throw an error **saying** "invalid regular expression", you need to put together a complete character class.

```
gsub('[][]', '', p1)
```

I would recommend reading up on [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) ...

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
x = 'mycharac[ter]'
gsub('\\[|\\]','',x)
#[1] "mycharacter"
```